# What SPN do I need to set for a net.tcp service?

Tags: wcf, security, spn

I have a wcf application hosted in a windows service running a local windows account. Do I need to set an SPN for this account? If so, what's the protocol the SPN needs to be set under? I know how to do this for services over HTTP, but have never done it for net.tcp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default (i.e. out of the box) net.tcp services are unsecured and don't perform any authentication at all. So you won't need (and in fact can't) set a service principal name.

If you need to authenticate, then check the [net.tcp security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpsecurity.aspx) modes on MSDN. The best way to understand the different combinations is to experiment!

Comment: Hey, chaps, why the downvotes? Pur-lease comment at the very least so we can all learn.

Comment: I have no idea - it helped me. Here's a +1 to cheer you up :)

Answer (score 6):

Change the service account to an AD account and register the SPN's as shown. Use your own service name e.g. fooservice

> setspn -A fooservice/servermachinename domain\serviceAccountName
>   setspn -A fooservice/servermachinename.fullyqualifieddomainname
>   domain\serviceAccountName

In the client config set:

```
<identity>
    <serviceprincipalname value="fooservice/servermachinename" />
</identity>
```