# IIS hosted net.tcp WCF service not working remotely

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, net.tcp

I have created a WCF service as part of a web application using net.tcp on port 808. Details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628382/setting-up-wcf-tcp-service-in-a-web-application)

It works on my development machine and it works locally on the server where it is deployed, but it doesn't work from other servers. It gives the following error when called remotely:

> SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

The firewall is completely open and it's possible to telnet to port 808 remotely.

What could be wrong?